# Using RedisTemplate set a value but get Nil from Terminal Redis-CLI

Tags: redis, spring-data

1.Set key `name` with `alex` using `Spring data redis` Library.

```
 @Test
public void testOne() throws Exception {
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("name","alex");
}
```

2.Try get name from Terminal with `redis-cli` but get Nil

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get name
(nil)
```

3.However `alex` can be retrieve like this

```
Object hello = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("name");
System.out.println(hello);
-----
alex
```

Can anyone explain this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedisTemplate` converts keys and values depending on the configured `RedisSerializer`s (see [6.7 Serializers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer)). The default is  `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`.

Given the String `name` the actual key in redis looks like:

```
GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer  : "name"
JacksonJsonRedisSerializer:         : "name"
Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer:        : "name"
JdkSerializationRedisSerializer     : \xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x04name
OxmSerializer with XStreamMarshaller: <string>name</string>
StringRedisSerializer               : name
```

So in case you intend to just work with Strings the [convenience classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:string) like `StringRedisTemplate` might be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try surround the key with `"`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set some `serializer` options on your `RedisTemplate` like below

```
private RedisTemplate<String, ?> createRedisTemplateForEntity() {

    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getRedisConnectionFactory());

    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

where `getRedisConnectionFactory()` returns your Redis connection (ie: `JedisConnectionFactory`).